# How can I completely reset my Ruby installation?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro Linux 18.0.4. I seem to have accidentally uninstalled some Ruby gems, or interrupted installation by doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

I tried uninstalling all gems with:

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

and an error code pops up:

```sh
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::RDoc
```

I also tried uninstalling Ruby itself through pamac.

I'd just like to start over. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get purge <packages>` this is what I follow when I completely want to start fresh.
So, it would be something like `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems`

Note: `purge` will delete its configuration files too.

I always suggest people to install ruby using `rvm`

Comment: I don't think that there is any equivalent for this, But you can try `# pacman -Rc perl-libwww` in order to remove packages. Note: `c` is a cascade delete.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error try installing these gems

```
gem install rdoc
gem update rake
```